# CentOS/RHEL user-systemd with network home directories

Tags: systemd, nfs, podman

I'm trying to deploy podman user services in a corporate network environment where all Linux users have their home directories NFS-mounted from a common file server. I'm not sure how to have computer-specific user-level services when my user's home-directory on every machine is nfs-mounted to the same share.

For podman to work cleanly with network home directories, I've found that I'm going to need to set `graphroot` setting to point to somewhere on each local machine, otherwise the containers on each machine will try to use the same storage and get confused. Ok, I can do that (though will take some work with IT to set this up).

When turning pods/containers into user-level services (using `podman generate systemd`) I'd ordinarily put the `.service` file in `~/.config/systemd/user` but this is also on the network share and thus would affect my user in every location.

Is there a standard way to get around this issue? **How do I have user-level services on a per-machine basis** (i.e. I may want different machines to have different services, especially if these services are containers referenced by their ID)?

Bonus question extension: I also intend to set `loginctl enable-linger`. Since the NFS home directories are lazy-mounted, will this actually result in services being started on boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a standard way to get around this issue? How do I have user-level services on a per-machine basis (i.e. I may want different machines to have different services, especially if these services are containers referenced by their ID)?

Use the [Condition*=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conditions%20and%20Asserts) directives.

```
[Unit]
# System hostname (/proc/sys/kernel/hostname)
ConditionHost=|node520
ConditionHost=|node964
```

```
[Unit]
# /etc/machine-id check
ConditionHost=7539689722fb45bca1a4e101447e4930
```

> Bonus question extension: I also intend to set loginctl enable-linger. Since the NFS home directories are lazy-mounted, will this actually result in services being started on boot?

If you are using autofs, the `systemd --user` process attempting to access each user's ~/.config will trigger the lazy-mount in the same way that e.g. cronjobs would.

(This will not quite work if you're using NFS with Kerberos.)

If the lazy-mount is triggered using PAM, it will happen *if* `/etc/pam.d/systemd-user` invokes the necessary PAM modules. (Again, exactly like with cronjobs, it will only trigger 'account' and 'session' modules but won't go through 'auth'.)

Comment: Awesome - thank you so much for this response! A followup question: does the use of `loginctl enable-linger` cause the system to trigger the PAM modules after boot (thereby causing autofs to mount and the systemd user services to start)?

Comment: PAM and autofs are usually completely unrelated – there's no "thereby" here. Yes, the user@UID.service will be started on boot if linger is on, and will call PAM open_session when it's started (which it'll do regardless of linger mode being on or off, the only difference is when that happens), and yes, user@UID.service will also cause autofs to mount the user's home, but that's not because of PAM but because the actual systemd --user process directly tries to access files from the homedir.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize there was a user@UID.service; that makes perfect sense! Thank you again!